# Create 3 level master-detail grid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, master-detail

I'm trying to create a gridview with 3 level Master Detail View.

My View Should Contain:

- Invoices
- InvoiceLines
- InvoiceLineDetails

I use the following code:

```
public partial class Manage_Other_Company_Invoices : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
{
    private int companyID;
    DataAccess_CompanyInvoice dal = new DataAccess_CompanyInvoice();
    DataSet dataSet; 

    public Manage_Other_Company_Invoices(int companyID)
    {
        this.companyID = companyID;
        DisplayData();
    }

    private DataSet GetItems()
    {
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.Clear();
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dal.CreateInvoiceTable(companyID));
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dal.CreateInvoiceLinesTable());
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dal.CreateInvoiceLineDetailsTable());

        DataColumn keyColumn1 = dataSet.Tables["Invoice"].Columns["invoiceID"];
        DataColumn foreignKeyColumn1 = dataSet.Tables["InvoiceLines"].Columns["invoiceID"];
        dataSet.Relations.Add("Invoice", keyColumn1, foreignKeyColumn1, false);

        DataColumn keyColumn2 = dataSet.Tables["InvoiceLines"].Columns["company_Invoice_Line_ID"];
        DataColumn foreignKeyColumn2 = dataSet.Tables["InvoiceLineDetails"].Columns["InvoiceLineID"];
        dataSet.Relations.Add("InvoiceLineInvoiceLineDetails", keyColumn2, foreignKeyColumn2,false);

        return dataSet;
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("test" + GetItems().Tables["Invoice"].Rows.Count.ToString());
        gridControl.DataSource = GetItems().Tables["Invoice"];
        gridControl.ForceInitialize();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I take the test line out of comment in my `DisplayData()` function, it shows the correct amount of rows in that table. But the weird thing is, is that the line after throws a null reference exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see nothing related to DevExpress here... Have you tried to extract the `GetItems()` result into the local variable? It seems the `GetItems` method is not reentrant.

Comment: Have you tried just using the DataSet as the for the GridControl's DataSource?

Comment: I have concluded that the problem is because gridControl is seen as `null` after intense troubleshooting. i still don't know how to fix this as i completely recreated the frontend, tried changing names, tried adding second gridcontrol,... but still don't know why the problem is ocurring